# A better understanding of javascript precompile

Tags: javascript, precompile

```js
var foo=1;
function bar(){
  foo=10;
  return;
  function foo(){}
}
bar();
alert(foo);
```

I am currently learning on how javascript is actually running in the machine and this is a piece of code I see in the example. I got no idea why the final alert is 1 instead of 10. So I am wondering could any one help me explain how the javascript virtual machine is actually execute these code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got no idea why the final alert is 1 instead of 10.

Because the `foo` in this line in `bar`:

```
foo = 10;
```

...is the variable-like thing* declared by the function declaration later on in that function:

```
function foo(){}
```

...**not** the `foo` that's outside `bar`. That is:

```
var foo=1;
function bar(){
  foo=10;             // <== This `foo`
  return;
  function foo(){}    // <== Is the `foo` declared here
}
bar();
alert(foo);
```

...not to the `foo` declared in the containing scope (`var foo`).

There are two reasons that's happening:

1. Function declarations are processed immediately on entry to the containing scope (the call to `bar`, in this case), prior to any step-by-step code in the function. This is sometimes called "hoisting" the declarations (because they happen as though they were at the very top). And since the function declaration isn't step-by-step code, the `return` has no effect on whether it gets processed; it gets processed before the `return` ever happens.
2. Function declarations also create what might as well be variables with the names of the functions. So the `foo` in the function declaration effectively becomes a variable with that name (more below) — and as you've seen in that code, you can assign new values to those "variables."

When you run that code, here's the order of things that the JavaScript engine does:

1. Creates a variable called `foo` and gives it the initial value `undefined`.
2. Creates the function `bar`, adding `bar` as an in-scope symbol (effectively a variable) in the current scope and making it a reference to the `bar` function.
3. Starts step-by-step code for that scope.
4. Assigns the value `1` to `foo`.
5. Calls the `bar` functon.
6. Creates the `foo` function relevant to that call to `bar`, adding `foo` as an in-scope symbol (effectively a variable) during the call and making it a reference to the function.
7. Starts the step-by-step code for that scope.
8. Assigns the value `10` to the local `foo` (which used to refer to the function).
9. Returns out of the function.
10. Calls `alert` with the `foo` in that scope, which still has the value `1`.

You can read up on all the gory details in [§10.4.3 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) and the sections it links to.

---

* "variable-like thing" In JavaScript, each *execution context* (the global context and any contexts created by calling functions, etc.) has an object that it uses to hold various names used in that context and their values; it's called a "binding object." The binding object for a context (I'm skipping some unrelated details here) has *properties* for each variable, function declaration, and a few other things like the `arguments` pseudo-array, the name of the function itself (referring back to the function), and such. The name of the properties are the names of the variables, declared functions, etc. That's why assigning to `foo` inside `bar` overwrites the reference to the `foo` function declared in `bar`, instead of assigning to the variable in the outer scope. `foo` is *effectively* a local variable in `bar`, even though it's not declared with `var`, because of the function declaration.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to [function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting):

```
var foo=1;
function bar(){
  function foo(){} // This gets moved up here by the engine
  foo=10; // You've reassigned the local `foo` function to 10,
          // leaving the global `foo` untouched
  return;
}
bar();
alert(foo); // Since the foo has never changed in this scope, it's still 1
```

Comment: if declaration of `foo` inside `bar` gets _moved_ to top, then applying the same behavior, doesn't declaration of `bar` gets moved before `var foo=1;` (real question, not a rhetorical one)?

Comment: @Ejay Correct. Meaning that if I called `bar()` *before* `function bar()`, the code would still succeed.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with a concept called *hoisting*. `function foo` is essentially just an alternative syntax for `var foo = function ..`, so inside `bar` the name `foo` does not refer to the outer `foo` variable but to a locally defined `foo`. This `foo` is first a function, but later gets overwritten by `10`.

Now, through hoisting the name `foo` is "reserved" and scoped at parse time, before the code executes. Essentially, it executes like this:

```
function bar(){
  var foo = function () {};
  foo = 10;
  return;
}
```

Hence it does not overwrite the outer variable at all.